# I want to assign 2 variables at the same time, which are in the function imported from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-3.7

I want to assign 2 variables at the same time, which are in the function imported from another file.

```
THIS IS THIS FUNCTION
def counter(init=[0]):
    init[0] += 1
    return init[0]
_____________________________________________
THIS IS ANOTHER SCRIPT


from Include.new_var import counter

first_letter = []

second_letter = []


def license_plate():
    global first_letter, second_letter

    characters = string.ascii_uppercase

    prices_for_letters = dict(zip(characters, range(1, len(characters) + 1)))

    print(prices_for_letters)
```

Actual results:

```
counter(first_letter), counter(second_letter) = random.choice(list(prices_for_letters.items()))
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Expected results:

`new variable`

I want to generate automaticlly new variables which will be storing random chosen value.

Comment: Do you want to randomly assign two distinct letters to a license plate?

Comment: You do the equivalent of `counter([]) = 1.23` (1.23 being some random value). That doesn't make sense. What do you want to happen?

Comment: If you want to increase the value, then assign to it, then do that in two steps: `counter(first_letter); counter(second_letter); first_letter, second_letter = random.choice(...`.

Comment: Please provide expecteed output also.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque  I want to generate new variables which will be storing randomly chosen values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assumptions:
1) Your function name seems to imply that you want to create a license plate.
2) Going through your profile, I see that you are from Poland so i assume you are trying to create a random license generator for vehicles in Poland.
3) A quick google search reveals that Poland license plates are 7 characters long with 2 or 3 initial chars followed by numbers.

def counter(some_char, draft_plate= []):
    draft_plate.append(str(some_char))
    return draft_plate

def license_plate():
    final_license_plate = []
    characters = string.ascii_uppercase
    numbers = range(0,10)
    prices_for_letters = dict(zip(characters, range(1, len(characters) + 1)))
    prices_for_numbers = dict(zip(numbers, range(1, len(numbers)+1)))
    numofchars = random.randint(2,3)
    for i in range(0,numofchars):
        counter(random.choice(list(prices_for_letters.keys())), final_license_plate)
    final_license_plate.append(' ')
    for j in range(numofchars,7):
        counter(random.choice(list(prices_for_numbers.keys())), final_license_plate)
    print(final_license_plate)

license_plate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify what you're intending to do afterwards? Here you're just trying to call the function twice.

Please also provide an expected result etc.

**However:**

1. First, choice will only return one item - you're expecting two.
2. Second, just put the choice statement into your function call:

```
counter(random.choice(list(prices_for_letters.items())))
counter(random.choice(list(prices_for_letters.items())))
```

Comment: This is the "counter" function:                                                                                    
```def counter(init=[0]):
       init[0] += 1
       return init[0]```      (and I want to crate new variable which will be stroing another value, but I want to generate this new vars)